# Why deleting event listeners, ever?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer

From the [Polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events) about event listeners:

> Use automatic node finding and the convenience methods listen and > unlisten.

```
this.listen(this.$.myButton, 'tap', 'onTap');
this.unlisten(this.$.myButton, 'tap', 'onTap');
The listener callbacks are invoked with this set to the element instance.
```

> If you add a listener imperatively, you need to remove it imperatively. This is commonly done in the attached and detached callbacks. If you use the listeners object or annotated event listeners, Polymer automatically adds and removes the event listeners.

Questions:

- Why is it important to only listen to events of elements in the local DOM after `attached()`, to then remove them when `detached()`?
- Aren't event listeners deleted automatically when the observed DOM object is destroyed?
- Would this also apply to when you listen to events for elements in your light DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer only removes event listeners it added itself. If you add event listeners yourself (imperatively) you need to remove them yourself.
Code might not be able to get garbage collected if event listeners are referring code.

Comment: "Code might not be able to get garbage collected if event listeners are referring code" -- what if the code is garbage collected, since the DOM element is deleted?

Comment: Removing the element from the DOM is not related to GC. If the element is referenced to from anywhere else in code it doesn't matter if it is currently added to the DOM or not. If the element is self-contained without references from or to it, then removing event listeners might be redundant but as @Whothehellisthat said "better safe than sorry". It's always good practice to free all resources that you requested.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it's just best practise. Older browsers don't handle removal of old events correctly, and if functions have scope references they can cause memory leaks. I guess it's a convention along the lines of "better safe than sorry."

Comment: I disagree, it's not just a matter of convention . If you test in the most recent version of chrome event, the event listener won't be removed and so the handler will be called every time unless you remove the listener. That can easily cause problem